# Is $|\mathbb{R}^{\omega_1}| > \aleph_1$?

Tags: set-theory

Intuatively I'd guess no, since $|\omega_1^{\omega_1}| = \aleph_1$.

But then there's cardinal exponentiation $\aleph_1^{\aleph_1}\geq2^{\aleph_1}=\aleph_2$.

A formal explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: $2^{\aleph_1}$ is not necessarily $\aleph_2$; it is consistent with $\mathsf{ZFC}$ that $2^{\aleph_1}$ be any cardinal of cofinality greater than $\omega_1$. $\left|\Bbb R^{\omega_1}\right|=\left|\left(2^{\aleph_0}\right)^{\aleph_1}\right|=2^{\aleph_0\cdot\aleph_1}=2^{\aleph_1}>\aleph_1$.

Comment: When you write $\omgea_1^{\omega_1}$, that makes me think about *ordinal* exponentiation. But when you write $\Bbb R^{\omega_1}$ that makes me think about *all* functions between the two sets, which would correspond to *cardinal* exponentiation. If you mean something else, you should specify what.

Answer (score 3):

Write $\Bbb R=2^{\aleph_0}$, so $$|\Bbb R|^{\aleph_1}=(2^{\aleph_0})^{\aleph_1}=2^{\aleph_0\cdot\aleph_1}=2^{\aleph_1}>\aleph_1,$$
where I used that for infinite cardinals $\kappa,\lambda$ we have $\kappa\cdot\lambda=\max\{\kappa,\lambda\}$.

Also note that $2^{\aleph_1}=\aleph_2$ is independent of $\mathsf{ZFC}$, but nonetheless we have $2^{\aleph_1}>\aleph_1$ by Cantor's theorem.

Comment: You didn't really need $\kappa\cdot\lambda=\max\{\kappa,\lambda\}$ since you could have simply written $2^{\aleph_0\cdot\aleph_1}\ge2^{\aleph_1}$ or just $(2^{\aleph_0})^{\aleph_1}\ge2^{\aleph_1}$.

Comment: It felt cleaner to write equalities as far as possible, but that's a good point

Comment: I see. I would have avoided using $\kappa\lambda=\max(\kappa,\lambda)$ because that's a more difficult result that the OP may not have learned yet, given the level of the question.